# Issue "Exception in thread "main"# START NON-TRANSLATABLEjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: G€“Xmx3072m" (MyEclipse 12.0 Blue & Websphere7)

Tags: deployment, websphere, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 14.0 Blue & Websphere7. I am trying to deploy into the Websphere via Server tab, and when it starts to deploy I am getting below issue.

```
****Exception in thread "main"# START NON-TRANSLATABLEjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: G€“Xmx3072m
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: G€“Xmx3072m
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
Could not find the main class: GÇôXmx3072m.  Program will exit.****
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, as the stack trace says, it is trying to find a class, "GÇôXmx3072m", which is obviously not what was intended. We'd need the rest of the deployment log to try to figure this out. There might also be a problem with the server connector configuration. However, it's not clear what release of MyEclipse you're using. Does "14.0" refer to release 2014 (releases have  been designated by the main year, since 2013) or to 2016 (which has an internal release number of 14.0)? The server connector architecture changed after release 2014.

Comment: I Couldn't find a way to solve this issue. So I did a work around on it. I have uninstalled the websphere and reinstalled it again. It is working again. I've followed the link below to uninstall it: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.wmqwasmig2v7.doc/topics/mig_unins_wasV7.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have typo in your jvm configuration so it thinks max heap size param (`-Xmx3072m`) is a classpath variable, please check configuration.

Comment: I've already tried to find where it is set as -Xmx3072m, but I couldnt find any configuration using this max heap size param. I've already looked at the jvm configuration and it is using a different param values. Do you know where else I can look?

Comment: On server tab in eclipse, right click on websphere 7 server definition, open admin console, then go to **Application servers > {servername} > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine** , check configuration parameters. Most probably, you have a typo in **Generic JVM arguments**

Comment: This is my Generic JVM arguments, I can't find any typo on it.

`-Denv=dev -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=http://coherence.com/config.xml -Dtangosol.coherence.log=c:/coherence.log -Dtangosol.coherence.log.level=1 -Dcom.log4j=C:/ -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -DdefaultAppId=FACS`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by fixing the global PATH variable.
One variable had two quotes around it which messed up the path for the websphere...

A second thing would be to check for any characters that would be invalid for batch files or scripts in the operating system (because your problem seems to be encoding related)

Some more hints you may find [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21675482).